# How can I set up ESP3212 after unpacking?

Tags: esp8266, esp32

Do I need to flash/burn some firmware?Is there a dedicated github page/website?

Comment: My goal is to create a communication node, where an array of Bluetooth devices communicate with each other and are remotely controlled via the internet.

Comment: Check the documentation of the ERP3212, use Google, use Github search bar.

Comment: I did all that, before posting here. ESP3212 has a datasheet in Chinese. Secondly, searching on GitHub had no tangible results

Comment: Maybe check the quality of support before buying next time?

Comment: Can Google translate help with the Chinese information sheet? Can you find someone Chinese, maybe at a local university?

Answer (score 3):

You can start watching [this unboxing video](https://youtu.be/lByVGYm6iFo) for the basic flow of installing and mounting the device.

Tutorial uses [Espressif Github project for Arduino](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/) which has the same instructions in written format for quite many platforms.

With these you can first install esp32 support for Arduino IDE and with the IDE there are several ready tutorials that call you for running them and use as a basis for further project development when you get the basics right.